# Deploy multiple Rails applications on a single EC2 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have two rails applications on a single EC2 machine at different locations. I would like to have app1.domain1.com to point to one of them while app1.domain1.com to point to another.

I have two records in Route53 to point app1.domain1.com and app2.domain1.com to same IP address and had nginx config route

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app1.domain1.com;
    root <path_to_app1>;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app2.domain1.com;
    root <path_to_app2>;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

how ever it appears that even when i try app2.domain1.com it is taking me to app1.

Comment: I don't see anything different between to nginx config here and the one I use. So I know this may seen stupid, but have you restarted the nginx service?

Comment: thanks @veereecjw ... i restarted rails server and forgot to restart the server/nginx. It works now!